# How to set the position for newly created Image

Tags: android, imageview, touch-event, ontouchlistener

In my application i have multiple images side by side. I am able to create new image when touching the particular image, but the newly created image is always added at first position only. how to add the newly created image on touched position. Below is my code

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(100,100));
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            status = START_DRAGGING;
            m_lastTouchX = me.getX();
            m_lastTouchY = me.getY();
            imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

            layout.addView(imageView,params);
        }
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            status = STOP_DRAGGING;
            Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
        } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
                System.out.println("Dragging");
                m_dx = me.getX() - m_lastTouchX;
                m_dy = me.getY() - m_lastTouchY;
                m_posX = m_prevX + m_dx;
                m_posY = m_prevY + m_dy;
                params.leftMargin = (int) m_posX;
                params.topMargin=(int) m_posY;
                imageView.bringToFront();
                imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: pass the index when you add new imageView to layout.

Comment: i tried like layout.addView(imageView, view.getId(), params); but not working

Comment: layout.addView(imageView, index) this version of addview. Set params to your imageView before you add it to layout.

Comment: i tried imageView.setLayoutParams(params);layout.addView(imageView, view.getId(), params); still not working...

Comment: don't use the above code. see my previous comment. for index getchildcount of your layout and use that.

Comment: getchildcount is returning total images count...

Comment: yes. so add one to it and use it as your new image index.

Comment: i think you didn't get my question...i need to add image at user touched position...when i add new view it is automatically added to the layout but it is always at first position..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49028/discussion-between-amrut-and-vamshi)

Comment: Try out as by setting parameters of layout by last x,y position. `if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { status = START_DRAGGING;
            m_lastTouchX = me.getX();
            m_lastTouchY = me.getY();  
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(m_lastTouchX ,m_lastTouchY));
layout.addView(imageView,params);`